# Search for a Keyword through All the Properties of an Entity, Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, filter

I am using the Lexik Form Filter Bundle to filter a result set from an entity repository.

```
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Lexik\Bundle\FormFilterBundle\Filter\Form\Type as Filters;

class ItemFilterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', Filters\TextFilterType::class)
            ->add('description', Filters\TextFilterType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'csrf_protection'   => false,
            'validation_groups' => array('filtering')
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'item_filter';
    }
}
```

As per the default behavior of this filter, the final query which is built after attaching the filter conditions, will have the following **WHERE** condition structure.

```
SELECT * FROM AppBundle\Entity\Item a WHERE
a.name = 'nameValue'
AND a.description = 'descriptionValue'
```

(Assume the conventional directory structure)

My task is to add one more field to the filter form. This will not be attached to any particular property. Upon submission of the filter form, this input has to be searched through all the properties of the entity. In other words, the resulting query has to be something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM AppBundle\Entity\Item a WHERE
a.name LIKE '%nameValue%'
OR a.description LIKE '%descriptionValue%'
```

(Please note the keywords **OR** and **LIKE** here.)

I prefer to adhere to the way Lexik Filter maintains the filter data (using the session), so it is better if I can achieve this using this filter. But I am clueless about what type of custom field I need to create and how I can alter the condition builder logic. Since this keyword is not attached to a specific property, is this even possible using this filter?

Comment: You don't use listener for create your queryBuilder ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @darkomen. I have taken that approach to override the default way to apply the filter. I still have the problem of building the condition using the metadata of whatever the underlying entity.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the 'apply_filter' option of all filter types.
Documentation can be seen here [Lexik Form Filters - Customize Condition Operators](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/working-with-the-bundle.md#i-customize-condition-operator)

My keyword filter looks like this, searching on 5 fields; *$fields*

```
->add('keyword', TextFilterType::class, array(
    'required' => false,
    'attr' => array(
        'placeholder' => 'Keyword..'
    ),
    'apply_filter' => function(QueryInterface $filterQuery, $field, $values) {
        if($values['value'] === null || $values['value'] === '') {
            return null;
        }

        /** @var Expr $expr */
        $expr = $filterQuery->getExpr();

        $fields = [
            'exhibitorName',
            'exhibitorStandNumber',
            'address.city',
            'address.postcode',
            'address.country',
        ];

        $params = [];
        $expression = $expr->orX();  ///andX for must match all




        foreach($fields as $field) {
            $paramName = sprintf('p_%s', str_replace('.','_', $field));
            $ex = $expr->like($field, ':' . $paramName);
            $expression->add($ex);
            $params[$paramName] = '%' . $values['value'] . '%';
        }

        return $filterQuery->createCondition($expression, $params);
    }
))
```